# Discord.js sending message with @person and #channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

With my discord bot, i am trying to create a welcome message.
I got the following working:

- Sending a message when someone joins
- Getting the name of the person who joins

Now the problem I have is with doing a @ or # in that message. I use the following code for the message:

```
const welcomeMessage = `Welcome @${member.user.username} to the server! Please look through the #:page_with_curl:rules and assign yourself a role at #:mortar_board:role-assignment`;
```

But I have also tried:

```
Welcome @${member.user.username} to the server! Please look through the #rules and assign yourself a role at #role-assignment
```

Both of them do not what i want them do to. I am getting the following result from this code:
[image: Message of bot without the blue outline of @ and #]

What you can see there is that the `@MEE6` and the 2 channel # is not blue, and not clickable. But when I copy the full text, past it and send it in the chat it does show blue.

The result I would like to have is the result of when I copy, paste and send it. That is the following:
[image: Message of my with the blue outline of @ and #]

Here is a little more of the code:

```
const welcomeChannel = client.channels.cache.get('738678076174630922');
const welcomeMessage = `Welcome @${member.user.username} to the server! Please look through the #rules and assign yourself a role at #role-assignment`;

welcomeChannel.send(welcomeMessage)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: About the member just change `member.user.username` to `member` it will link automatically no need to add @

Comment: @Cursed Yes, i see. Thx!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const welcomeMessage = `Welcome ${member}! Please look through the <#id-of-rules-channel-here> and assign yourself a role at <#id-of-role-assignment-channel-here>`
```

You can auto-embed  Discord classes like channels and members if you already have them stored in a variable (like you do for `member`), or you can use their IDs in text directly in the form `<#id>` for channels or `<@id>` for users.